# Unexpected Behavior Scraping Images With Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, if-statement, web-scraping

Can someone help me understand why my function here doesn't return each individual url in the list of urls I provide as a parameter and why I am getting the following output?  I am simply trying to return the url for each item and the list and all the corresponding images for the item for each url.

```
beta_test_items = ['https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/2009940172578816',
 'https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/1591865710899243']

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def scrape_item_details(beta_test_items):
    #finish this function
    for url in beta_test_items:
        images = []
        driver.get(url)
        sleep(3)
        image_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[contains(@class, "_5m")]')
        images = [image_element.get_attribute('src')]

        try:
            previous_and_next_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//i[contains(@class, '_3ffr')]")
            next_image_button = previous_and_next_buttons[1]
            print(next_image_button.text)
            if  next_image_button.is_displayed():
                next_image_button.click()

                image_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//img[contains(@class, "_5m")]')
                print(image_element.get_attribute('src'))
                sleep(2)   

                if image_element.get_attribute('src') in images:
                    pass
                else:
                    images.append(image_element.get_attribute('src'))

            else:
                pass
        except:
            pass

        yield(url, images)

if __name__ == '__main__':
```

I get the following output when I try it run it currently and Im not sure why its stopping on the first url after the second photo is appended to the list of images:

```
In [46]: scrape_item_details(beta_items_list)
['https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27750896_2002108023449096_2229019388723795634_n.jpg?oh=26d3fe06595affdcbd142754766fe934&oe=5B0933C9']
Next
https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27655331_2002108026782429_4575620607831413757_n.jpg?oh=a7c94bc2b8ef8b39bc65291b641f7953&oe=5B0A11DD
Out[46]: 
('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/2009940172578816',
 ['https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27750896_2002108023449096_2229019388723795634_n.jpg?oh=26d3fe06595affdcbd142754766fe934&oe=5B0933C9',
  'https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27655331_2002108026782429_4575620607831413757_n.jpg?oh=a7c94bc2b8ef8b39bc65291b641f7953&oe=5B0A11DD'])
```

----Update----
I changed return to yield and when I run `list(scrape_item_details(beta_test_items))` I get the following output:

```
[('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/2009940172578816',
  ['https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27750896_2002108023449096_2229019388723795634_n.jpg?oh=26d3fe06595affdcbd142754766fe934&oe=5B0933C9',
   'https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27655331_2002108026782429_4575620607831413757_n.jpg?oh=a7c94bc2b8ef8b39bc65291b641f7953&oe=5B0A11DD',
   'https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27973017_1685674758138175_781683034741350935_n.jpg?oh=e2aa32aa73f3bb9061e861bd1ea306cb&oe=5B0741FF']),
 ('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/item/1591865710899243',
  ['https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27750896_2002108023449096_2229019388723795634_n.jpg?oh=26d3fe06595affdcbd142754766fe934&oe=5B0933C9',
   'https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27655331_2002108026782429_4575620607831413757_n.jpg?oh=a7c94bc2b8ef8b39bc65291b641f7953&oe=5B0A11DD',
   'https://scontent-atl3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/27973017_1685674758138175_781683034741350935_n.jpg?oh=e2aa32aa73f3bb9061e861bd1ea306cb&oe=5B0741FF'])]
```

Not sure why the images from the first url are repeating as the input for the second url?

Comment: Can you fix the indentation and provide the desired output?

Comment: just did. should be ok now. sorry about that

Comment: `return` means the execution of the function is stopped immediately, so you don't even have 2 loop runs. Maybe you meant `yield (url, images)`? Then you can call the function like that: `list(scrape_item_details(beta_items_list))`

Comment: much closer now, for some reason though the images for the second url are the list of images from the first url

Comment: add `images = []` right after `for url in beta_test_items:` to reset the list of images for every url. But it looks like you won't load new images anyways cause `if first:` will be `False`. Sorry, I'm just not sure why you have this condition.

Comment: Thanks, almost there now.  I made adjustments and removed is_first and added images = [].  Now I get the correct url and the first two images of each unique url but it still doesn't include the last image of each url?

Comment: Probably you have an error inside `try-except`, but you never know since you do nothing after catching it. It's definitely a bad practice. At least `print("ERROR")` in the `except:`. My guess is that last image has just one button with `_3ffr` class, so line `next_image_button = previous_and_next_buttons[1]` throws out of range exception. I might be wrong, I didn't run your code.

Comment: Thanks.  Ill experiment and take your advice.  I don't think its an out of range issue because the previous and next buttons never go away and you can loop through all the images infinitely.

Comment: Oh, I know! Now I noticed you're missing another loop. Wrap `try-except` with `while True:` and change `if image_element.get_attribute('src') in images: pass` to `if image_element.get_attribute('src') in images: break`

Comment: do you mean change this line to ```while next_image_button.is_displayed():``` underneath the try/except?  If I use break, does it just break the while loop or my entire script altogether?

Comment: That worked.  Thanks so much!!!

Comment: It just breaks the most-inner loop you're in. You can either use exactly the code I gave you in the last comment or follow your idea (but then you have to compute `next_image_button` right before this `while` and then again at the end of the loop run, so that it's always up-to-date when checking `is_displayed()`)